# Print rectangle based on inches results in wrong size

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

Trying to print a rectangle in inches based on the printer dpi. The width of the printable area reports to be 850 on a 8.5x11 sheet of paper, and the dpi is reporting 600. This is strange. I tried to multiply the inches * dpi and i get a box way too big. (obviously)
i am getting the dpi from

```cs
PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterResolution.X;
```

result is 600
What am I missing here, and why is the width so terribly off from the resolution?

```cs
PrintDataPage dp = PrintData[Pageno];
float yloc = Top;
Rectangle Box = new();
PointF point;
int dpi = prdc.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterResolution.X;
// float pry = prdc.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterResolution.Y;
int bFixWidth =(int) (dpi * 1.875f);
int bFixHeight = (int)(dpi * .1875f);
```

Comment: Please show the relevant code. In GDI+ the unit is "pixel" unless you applied a scale transform. How are you converting inches to pixels?

Comment: `    PrintDataPage dp = PrintData[Pageno];
            float yloc = Top;
            Rectangle Box = new();
            PointF point;
            int dpi = prdc.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterResolution.X;
           //     float pry = prdc.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterResolution.Y;
            
            int bFixWidth =(int) (dpi *  1.875f);
            int bFixHeight = (int)(dpi * .1875f) ;`

Comment: i think the solution's is in understanding why the printer reporrts a width of only 850 for an 8.5 x 11 sheet of paper, and my dpi is 600. Is there some kind of conversion I am missing ?

Comment: as shown in the code above width = dpi *1.875f should equal a width of 1.875 inches?

Comment: but again when I get the print area width I see 850. It does not make sense. should be closer to 10 inches like 8,500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some tests and have found that the `Graphics.PageUnit` is set to `GraphicsUnit.Display`. Therefore, change it to `GraphicsUnit.Pixel` to get the desired result.

```cs
private void Pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    int dpi = e.PageSettings.PrinterResolution.X;
    e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel; // <== This fixes the scaling problem.

    float sizeInInches = 1.0f;

    // Draws a rectangle of one inch in size at the upper left page margins.
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, 0, 0, dpi * sizeInInches, dpi * sizeInInches);
}
```

Note that I set `printDocument.OriginAtMargins = true;`. Otherwise you will have to add the margins manually.

I also made a test by setting the units to `GraphicsUnit.Inch` to be able to draw in inches directly. But for an unknown reason, this did not work.

Comment: That was it !!! Many thanks! fyi; ChatGPT did not find the right answer.

Comment: Luckily humans are better than AI (yet!).